# How to align text in two columns under table or image that is wide as page?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, two-column

I write two column document. At some point I inserted table that is wide as page. But the text that goes under the table, in two columns are not aligned i.e. text in left column continues one or two lines lower than the text in right column that continues just under the table. How to align text under the table so the tops of the columns are in the same line?

Comment: Could you please add a compilable example code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could post a small, but complete, code reproducing your problem?

Comment: by default the columns would start at the same point, so you must have some code forcing that extra space.

Comment: See if the related questions (to the right) cover your issue.